# Skip updating certain themes/modules on composer update

Tags: 8, composer

My setup is composer driven.

I have overridden some module with patches and customised a contributed theme (boostrap_sass).

Now I want to avoid overbidding these modules and theme when I perform composer update in console, so as to skip updating those modules and themes and perform update on only the modules, themes and core that I want to update via composer.

Comment: You might be looking at that the wrong way round. Rather than trying to explicitly exclude something (bootstrap_sass or whatever) from an update, consider whether you should be locking its version, and using cweagans/composer-patches to apply the patch(es). Then you don't get into dependency soup

Comment: Yep use exact versions in Composer. You can also pin to specific commit SHAs too if you need to require a dev branch.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pin a version of a module you could do so by running this in your console:

```
composer require drupal/module_name:1.1
```

In case you have many modules also see my contributed module:
[Composer Update Assistent](https://www.drupal.org/project/cua)

This module generates a commando to update all modules to the recommended version which can be copied to your console.

Comment: You forgot a disclaimer. This module is from you. 

Comment: You are right 